# why move swap part in bubble sort affect performance?

Tags: c++

why moving swap part on bubble sort to othe method affect performance as when I tried to make swap part on same method of bubble sort it takes about 23 seconds with input 100000 and when trying to move swap part to method it tkaes with same input about 130 seconds

I tried this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;


void swap(int& x, int& y)
{
    int temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}


void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
            {
                int temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
void bubbleSort2(int arr[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
        {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
            {
                swap(arr[j],arr[ j + 1]);
            }
        }
    }

}

int main()
{   
    const  int n = 100000;  
    int arr[n];
    int arr2[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = n - i;
        arr2[i] = n - i;
    }
    clock_t begin_time = clock(); 
    bubbleSort(arr, n);
    double ellipseSeconds = float(clock() - begin_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;//takes about 23 seconds

    begin_time = clock();
    bubbleSort2(arr2, n);
    ellipseSeconds = float(clock() - begin_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; //takes about 130 seconds


}
```

Comment: Declare the function with the specifier inline.

Comment: I tried to make this but didn't improve performance

Comment: cannot reproduce http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/716a869a0580447e

Comment: do you turn on optimization?

Comment: how to turn on optimization  i am using visual studio 2019?

Comment: I believe it's  `/O2`

Comment: Could I ask you to put you reply as a comment and i will verify it as an accepted solution ?

Answer (score 0):

that's due to the fact that swap is being called lots of times which is more heavy than doing it directly like in method 1.

Bubblesort is a very slow algorithm to sort an array that run in O(n²) , you can use the built-in sort function available in the algorithm library which runs in O(nlogn).

An example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include<algorithm>


int main()
{   
    const  int n = 100000;  
    int arr[n];
    int arr2[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = n - i;
        arr2[i] = n - i;
    }
    std::sort(arr, arr+n);

}
```

Comment: no i don't like to sort it quickly I know that bubble sort is very slow algorithm and i can use quick sort that is implemented in c++ in std library but i would like to now why moving swap to other method make it very slow when  i used c# and move swap to other method it doesn't affect on performance